# A farmer bought some chickens and cows from a local rancher...

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

A farmer bought some chickens and cows from a local rancher. If a chicken costs 2 dollars and a cow costs 5 dollars, how much of each can he purchase if the total cost is 38 dollars and he purchases more than 2 chickens and more than 2 cows.

Is this solution unique?

-Having a tough time with this problem, my professor's hint to me was that this is a linear Diophantine problem. This really didn't help me, as of now I understand that this could potentially be solved via contradiction to disprove the solution's uniqueness. Other than that any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A priest, a rabbi, and a minister walk into a bar...

Comment: Hint:  given that the farmer buys at least $3$ chickens and at least $3$ cows, you can remove that cost ($\$21$).  Hence he now has $\$17$ to spend on chickens and cows with no other constraints.  (N.B. You don't say if he is required to spend all the money...for example, he could buy $8$ more chickens which would leave him with $\$1$...is that acceptable?)

Comment: You can also consider this: since the number of cows $ \ ( y ) \ $ and chickens $ \ ( x ) \ $ have to be integers, and the number of dollars to be spent is an integer, you can only trade 5 chickens for 2 cows to maintain all of the numbers involved as integers.  Your "governing equation" is $ \ 2 \ x \ + \ 5 \ y \ = \ 38 \ $ .  Does this allow more than one possible pair of values $ \ ( x, \ y ) \ $ ?  (Consider also where the "intercepts" of this line are.)

Comment: As @lulu mentioned, the farmer has $\$17$ to spend on chickens and cows. The **total** cost is $\$38$, hence the farmer spends the entire $\$17$ in the shop. Therefore, we have to solve $2x+5y=17$, where $x$ is the number of chickens, $y$ is the number of cows in addition to the $3$ of each that he already has. We see that there are 2 solutions, namely $x=6,y=1$ and $x=1,y=3$. That gives two solutions. If you weaken your hypothesis to "the farmer buys **atleast** two of each", then we get $2x+5y=24$,  which in fact has **3** solutions. So your professor is wrong; have a chat with him.

Comment: @abdefghijklmnopqrtxyz-stoo His professor isn't wrong. A linear diophantine equation **can** have multiple solutions.

Comment: oh yesy. his professor isn't wrong. What's wrong is why he assumed  the solution should be unique. Thanks for pointing that out!